# Relative sizing with CSS flex-shrink

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to display several 3-4 widgets in a single vertical column. Each widget contains a table with a dynamic number of fixed-height rows. I'm trying to accomplish the following:

1. Widgets should auto-size to their content (remaining as small as possible) (flex-basis:auto)
2. Widgets should not grow (never appear larger than their content) (flex-grow:0)
3. Widgets should shrink (showing scrollbars) when the parent container is full (flex-shrink:>0)
4. Widgets should shrink relative to the size of their content (larger widgets should shrink more than smaller widgets) (flex-shrink:items.length)

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with the last objective. I've tried using the item count as a value for flex-shrink, assuming it would shrink each widget relatively based on the number of items it contained. However, this doesn't work and leads to some strange/unexpected behavior.

Below is a code snippet demonstrating the issue (JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/87uwfkv3/5/). In this case (4 widgets of varying sizes) I'd like the second widget to show a single row (since it's only a single item), and the other 3 widgets to be (approximately) the same pixel height as one another with scrollbars.

```js
const App = () => (
  <div className="root">
    <Widget count={60} />
    <Widget count={1} />
    <Widget count={600} />
    <Widget count={40} />
  </div>
);

const Widget = ({ count }) => (
  <div className="widget" style={{flexShrink: count}}>
    {new Array(count).fill(0).map((o,i) => ( 
      <div key={i}>
        item {i+1}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.body)
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
html, body {
  background: #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
}

.root {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.widget {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```